# Dart - Export data from objectbox to firebase

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

Hi i need export the data created by objectbox to firebase. How could I do it if it is saved in a **.mdb** file, any ideas?

Comment: This question is very generic. Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to do? E.g. a basic solution is to write e.g. a Java app that opens the database, maps the contained objects to a JSON model and exports it (if I remember correctly, Firestore is JSON based?).

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. I had the idea to continue using objectbox as local database and only use firebase to be able to share the data between users that use the same database. Now I'm just writing code to map each model to the objectbox database and upload it directly to firebase. It is somewhat tedious but I was wondering if there is any way already created or easier to do it.
Another idea would be to upload the .mdb to a server and synchronize between users, but I would have many conflicts when synchronizing, so I would have to create a panel for the user to resolve those conflicts.

Comment: The idea to upload the data.mdb file to a server would be the best if it were about a single user that modifies the information. But since I need several users to do it, I think there is no other way than the one you mentioned, mapping the information.

Comment: Yes, having separate models and mapping between them is the way to go from a software engineering perspective. It may appear like more work now, but in the future you will have much more flexibility (e.g. it will be easier to change either one without breaking the other).